# BIND resolves external addresses correctly, but doesn't resolve addresses in LAN

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, dns-hosting

I have recently set up a DNS server with bind (my first time) and I got it to resolve external addresses but internal addresses return an NXDOMAIN error in dig.

It for sure has to do something with my config but I cant find the solution.

named.conf:

```
options {
listen-on port 53 { 127.0.0.1; 213.190.31.0/24; };
//listen-on-v6 port 53 { ::1; };
directory   "/var/named";
dump-file   "/var/named/data/cache_dump.db";
statistics-file "/var/named/data/named_stats.txt";
memstatistics-file "/var/named/data/named_mem_stats.txt";
secroots-file   "/var/named/data/named.secroots";
recursing-file  "/var/named/data/named.recursing";
allow-query     { localhost; any; };

/* 
 - If you are building an AUTHORITATIVE DNS server, do NOT enable recursion.
 - If you are building a RECURSIVE (caching) DNS server, you need to enable 
   recursion. 
 - If your recursive DNS server has a public IP address, you MUST enable access 
   control to limit queries to your legitimate users. Failing to do so will
   cause your server to become part of large scale DNS amplification 
   attacks. Implementing BCP38 within your network would greatly
   reduce such attack surface 
*/
recursion yes;

dnssec-validation yes;

managed-keys-directory "/var/named/dynamic";
geoip-directory "/usr/share/GeoIP";

pid-file "/run/named/named.pid";
session-keyfile "/run/named/session.key";
    
    //hide version number from clients
    version "not currently available";

    querylog yes;
/* https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Changes/CryptoPolicy */
include "/etc/crypto-policies/back-ends/bind.config";
};

logging {
    channel default_debug {
            file "data/named.run";
            severity dynamic;
    };
 };

  zone "msgsolutions.eu" IN {

  type master;

  file "/var/named/msgsolutions.eu.db";

  allow-update {none;};

  }; 

  zone "31.190.213.in-addr.arpa" IN {

  type master;

  file "/var/named/213.190.31.db";

  allow-update {none;};
  };

include "/etc/named.rfc1912.zones";
include "/etc/named.root.key";
```

msgsolutions.eu.db:

```
$TTL 86400
@ IN SOA  dns.msgsolutions.eu. admin.msgsolutions.eu. (
                      2022030204    ;Serial
                      3600  ;Refresh
                      1800  ;Retry
                      604800 ;Expire
                      86400  ;Minimum TTL
 )

 @  IN NS   dns.msgsolutions.eu.
 @  IN A    213.190.31.58
 
 dns  IN A   213.190.31.58

 ftp IN CNAME www.msgsolutions.eu.
```

213.190.31.db:

```
$TTL 86400
@  IN  SOA   dns.msgsolutions.eu. root.msgsolutions.eu. (
        2022030203  ;Serial
        3600      ;Refresh
        1800    ;Retry
        604800   ;Expire
        86400   ;Minimum TTL
 )

 @  IN    NS   dns.msgsolutions.eu.

 100    IN   PTR   dns.msgsolutions.eu.

 101   IN   PTR    www.msgsolutions.eu.
```

dig output:

```
 dig 213.190.31.58

 ; <<>> DiG 9.16.23-RH <<>> 213.1090.31.58
 ;; global options: +cmd
 ;; Got answer:
 ;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 34679
 ;; flags: qr rd ra ad; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 1

 ;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
 ; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 1232
 ; COOKIE: 8e727de315c5fc7c0100000062fddb2fd3a3d7b28f598721 (good)
 ;; QUESTION SECTION:
 ;213.1090.31.58.                        IN      A

 ;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
 .                       10800   IN      SOA     a.root-servers.net. 
 nstld.verisign-grs.com. 2022081800 1800 900 604800 86400

 ;; Query time: 6 msec
 ;; SERVER: 213.190.31.58#53(213.190.31.58)
 ;; WHEN: Thu Aug 18 08:24:47 CEST 2022
 ;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 146
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The problem appears to be in your test, rather than the ISC bind configuration.

To perform a reverse lookup use either:

- the `-x` switch and `dig -x 213.190.31.58`
- or `dig -t PTR 58.31.190.213.in-addr.arpa.`

Comment: Yes. Because otherwise `dig 213.190.31.58` implicitely queries for `A` record (default record type used by `dig`) on a supposedly `.58` TLD, and hence the reply coming from root servers saying this TLD doesn't exist, hence no "name" below it exist as well.

Comment: I am still getting NXDOMAIN from dig even with -x.

Comment: I also tried forward lookup which led me to the same error. (cant edit previous comment for some reason).

Answer (score 0):

After trying "nslookup 213.190.31.58" I got an NXDOMAIN error while with "nslookup dns.msgsolutions.eu" it resolved fine. So it got to be a problem with my reverse zone.

The problem was that the reverse zone named wrong (31.190.213.in-addr.arpa. instead of 58.31.190.213.....) Now it works perfectly fine. Thanks for the help anyway!